# How to use environment variables in Path.Combine()?

Tags: c#, path, environment-variables

I am trying to read in from a file where a folder path is specified using environment variable shortcuts, like the following:

```
source          dest
filename.ext    %programfiles(x86)%\FolderName\
```

I get the following error when trying to use Path.Combine() to concatenate this with a filename:

```
"Could not find a part of the path %programfiles(x86)%\FolderName\filename.ext"
```

Do I have to parse environment variables (like %programfiles(x86)% and %appdata%) out and manually replace them, or is there a another way to have these resolved? Seems like a common use case for copying files, e.g. patching.

Comment: Side note: consider using [GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this to get the environment variable path

```
var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(value);
```